# Getting Cassandra datacenter name in cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

How can I get the name of the datacenter in `cqlsh`?
It's required for the constructor of `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
cqlsh> use system;
cqlsh:system> select data_center from local;

data_center
-------------
datacenter1
```